# Javascript SPA with OAuth2.0 Implicit Grant

Tags: javascript, security, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, api-design

I am planning to build an API that communicates with an SPA in ReactJS. I want to implement OAuth2.0 and have read around that the Implicit Grant is the way to go. However, I have also read that this grant should not be used any more.

What grant type should I use in this case where a user will be logging in and need a token to continue to use the app? I do not want to authenticate with a third party, but save the users data to my on system. Should I use 0Auth2.0? What grant should I use?

Should I use a raw JWT approach instead, or would that be incompatible with the use case of an app being built for this app?

Comment: Could you cite your resources that claim the implicit grant "should not be used anymore"?

Comment: I am using this package with Laravel to implement OAuth2.0 https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel. Here, the author of the package says that it is "no longer valid" https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/issues/37. I may have misinterpreted what he has said but it seems clear to me.

Comment: The link they point at the very end seems dead to me. Unfortunately, there are no other sensible references to anything you could consider as "facts". Are you aware of any other resources that would confirm there is a fundamental problem with this approach (like Google or Facebook making it deprecated)?

Comment: No, I have not read anything produced by Facebook or Google to support the implicit grant being deprecated. However, I have read on the PHP League that supports the main OAuth2.0 PHP package that they also have made this grant deprecated?

Comment: Interesting. I would die for more insight on that, not only from the php community though. Personally I implemented the implicit flow years ago on one of our identity providers and since that I haven't read anything that would make it obsolete. This is why I wonder so much what is really behind this.

Comment: I have read further into this to find that i can also use the password credentials grant, instead of the implicit grant. This is because the API will be communicating with a first part app that I created. Do you agree that I could implement this grant?

Comment: Of course, the only issue with the password grant is that users input the username/pwd pair on your custom window instead of the well-known and recognized web page they use normally.

Comment: I do not understand? Would they not be entering their username and password into my form on the React application?

Comment: Yes, they will. The question is only - will they trust your form enough. Suppose you are to implement the password flow to a Google service and you'd expect users to input their Google credentials on your React form instead of the usual Google login page. If this scenario fits you, the password flow is for you.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point now, thanks for clarifying. To clarify, I will only allow people to register on my site and no external services like Google will be used to login. So with this information, should i use the implicit flow now instead?

Comment: Sounds like it doesn't really matter and both will do.

Comment: Ok, thanks @WiktorZychla! I think I am going to use the Password Grant with a proxy that injects the client id and secret into the headers before it reaches the server.

Comment: wondered, how did you go on this? I'm on the same boat do agree that implicit is the right one for your front end based apps to get identity access token by redirecting the users to well-known login page. with client credentials you don't want to expose secret in the client side means you can't use it. Implicit is the way. having another issue now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45872664/implicit-grant-spa-with-identity-server4-concurrent-login